# Изменить стили в активном блоке

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть несколько блоков с товарами, по клику на блок нужно изменить стили дочерних элементов (у .sizes-block, .colors-block и прочих - display на block). Скрытые блоки должны отображаться только в активном блоке. Подскажите, как это сделать

```js
/*var cards = document.getElementsByClassName("card");
console.log(cards);

for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
  cards[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (cards[0].childNodes.className == "")
  });
}*/
```

```css
/*=======Products=======*/

.products_main-info {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 41px;
}
.products-label {
  font-size: 27px;
  letter-spacing: 2.825px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.products-info {
  color: #6e6e6e;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-top: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Cairo, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 17px;
  padding-left: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 88px;
}
.grid-2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 323.1px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 406.8px);
  grid-column-gap: 29px;
  grid-row-gap: 57px;
  align-items: stretch;
  max-width: 1025px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.card {
  background: #e6eef0;
  position: relative;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.card:hover {
  box-shadow: -1px 6px 25px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
}
.card_label {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 84.5%;
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 0 25px 0 25px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  font-size: 13px;
  letter-spacing: 1.05px;
  font-family: 'Cairo', sans-serif;
  line-height: 17.1px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 15px;
}
.card-1 {
  background-image: url(images/gothic-girl-by-lienskullova.png);
}
.card-2 {
  background-image: url(images/m1.png);
  background-position: 66%;
  background-size: 58%;
}
.card-3 {
  background-image: url(images/m3.png);
  background-position: 50% 1%;
  background-size: 73%;
}
.card-4 {
  background-image: url(images/model-7.png);
  background-size: 34%;
  background-position: 52% 3px;
}
.card-5 {
  background-image: url(images/model-10.png);
  background-position: 51%;
  background-size: 59%;
}
.card-6 {
  background-image: url(images/model-4.png);
  background-position: 48% 1%;
  background-size: 71%;
}
.price {
  color: #00cccc;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  letter-spacing: 1.7px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 26px;
  bottom: 24px;
}
.shopping-card_add {
  width: 176px;
  height: 40px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

/*======Products-Onclick======*/

.sizes-block{
  display: none;
}

.sizes{
  padding-bottom: 14px;
}

.colors-block{
  display: none;
}

.colors-logo{
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.colors{
  padding-bottom: 11px;
  padding-left: 3px;
}

.color{
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 7px;
}

.red{
  background: #ff0033;
}

.orange{
  background: #ff4200;
}

.blue{
  background: #33cccc;
}

.purple{
  background: #6666cc;
}


.add-button, .show-button{
  position: absolute;
  width: 114px;
  height: 34px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  display: none;
}

.button>a{
  color: #ffffff;
}

.add-button{
  top: 67px;
  left: 84px;
  line-height: 36px;
}

.show-button{
  top: 112px;
  line-height: 38px;
  left: 86px;
  letter-spacing: -0.2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="products">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="products_main-info">
      <h3 class="label products-label">our products</h3>
      <div class="products-info">new products every fucken <br> day.</div>
      <div class="grid-2">
        <div id="card" class="card card-1 card-onclick">
          <div class="button add-button"><a href="#">add to cart</a></div>
          <div class="button show-button"><a href="#">show gallery</a></div>
          <div class="card_label">
              <div class="dress-logo dl-onclick">fantastic black dress.</div>
              <div class="dress-caption dc-onclick">party dress</div>
              <div class="price">99$</div>
            <div class="sizes-block">
              <div class="sizes-logo">sizes</div>
              <div class="sizes">xs, sm, l, xl, xxl</div>
            </div>
            <div class="colors-block">
              <div class="colors-logo">colors</div>
              <div class="colors">
                <div class="color red"></div>
                <div class="color orange"></div>
                <div class="color blue"></div>
                <div class="color purple"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="card" class="card card-2">
          <div class="button add-button"><a href="#">add to cart</a></div>
          <div class="button show-button"><a href="#">show gallery</a></div>
          <div class="card_label">
              <div class="dress-logo dl-onclick">fantastic jeans.</div>
              <div class="dress-caption dc-onclick">summer dress</div>
              <div class="price">65$</div>
            <div class="sizes-block">
              <div class="sizes-logo">sizes</div>
              <div class="sizes">xs, sm, l, xl, xxl</div>
            </div>
            <div class="colors-block">
              <div class="colors-logo">colors</div>
              <div class="colors">
                <div class="color red"></div>
                <div class="color orange"></div>
                <div class="color blue"></div>
                <div class="color purple"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="card" class="card card-3">
          <div class="button add-button"><a href="#">add to cart</a></div>
          <div class="button show-button"><a href="#">show gallery</a></div>
          <div class="card_label">
              <div class="dress-logo dl-onclick">fantastic beat.</div>
              <div class="dress-caption dc-onclick">wintwe dress</div>
              <div class="price">65$</div>
            <div class="sizes-block">
              <div class="sizes-logo">sizes</div>
              <div class="sizes">xs, sm, l, xl, xxl</div>
            </div>
            <div class="colors-block">
              <div class="colors-logo">colors</div>
              <div class="colors">
                <div class="color red"></div>
                <div class="color orange"></div>
                <div class="color blue"></div>
                <div class="color purple"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="card" class="card card-4">
          <div class="button add-button"><a href="#">add to cart</a></div>
          <div class="button show-button"><a href="#">show gallery</a></div>
          <div class="card_label">
              <div class="dress-logo dl-onclick">fantastic jeans.</div>
              <div class="dress-caption dc-onclick" s>summer dress</div>
              <div class="price">99$</div>
            <div class="sizes-block">
              <div class="sizes-logo">sizes</div>
              <div class="sizes">xs, sm, l, xl, xxl</div>
            </div>
            <div class="colors-block">
              <div class="colors-logo">colors</div>
              <div class="colors">
                <div class="color red"></div>
                <div class="color orange"></div>
                <div class="color blue"></div>
                <div class="color purple"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="card" class="card card-5">
          <div class="button add-button"><a href="#">add to cart</a></div>
          <div class="button show-button"><a href="#">show gallery</a></div>
          <div class="card_label">
              <div class="dress-logo dl-onclick">fantastic jeans.</div>
              <div class="dress-caption dc-onclick">summer dress</div>
              <div class="price">65$</div>
            <div class="sizes-block">
              <div class="sizes-logo">sizes</div>
              <div class="sizes">xs, sm, l, xl, xxl</div>
            </div>
            <div class="colors-block">
              <div class="colors-logo">colors</div>
              <div class="colors">
                <div class="color red"></div>
                <div class="color orange"></div>
                <div class="color blue"></div>
                <div class="color purple"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="card" class="card card-6">
          <div class="button add-button"><a href="#">add to cart</a></div>
          <div class="button show-button"><a href="#">show gallery</a></div>
          <div class="card_label">
              <div class="dress-logo dl-onclick">fantastic beat.</div>
              <div class="dress-caption dc-onclick">wintwe dress</div>
              <div class="price">65$</div>
            <div class="sizes-block">
              <div class="sizes-logo">sizes</div>
              <div class="sizes">xs, sm, l, xl, xxl</div>
            </div>
            <div class="colors-block">
              <div class="colors-logo">colors</div>
              <div class="colors">
                <div class="color red"></div>
                <div class="color orange"></div>
                <div class="color blue"></div>
                <div class="color purple"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При клике на `block` самому `block`-у присваивается класс `active`, `.block.active .price` же в свою очередь имеет другой цвет, отличный от `.block .price`.

Кстати, таким же методом можно и показать/спрятать различные блоки(

`.block .some_block` - `{ display: none }`,

`.block.active .some_block` - `{ display: block }`

).

Примените эту же логику в свой код.

```js
$('.blocks').on('click', '.block', function() {
  $('.block').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

```css
.block {
  padding: 8px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.block.active .price {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blocks">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="price">$100.00</div>
   </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="price">$320.50</div>
   </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="price">$294.75</div>
   </div>
</div>
```